# What's the "less than dot" symbol mean in Chrome console output?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

Sometimes, but not always, when the result of an evaluation in the Chrome JavaScript console results in "undefined", there is a symbol in the left margin that looks like a less-than symbol with a dot.

Examples can be seen in [this section of the Chrome developer's tools documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console#controlling_the_cpu_profiler).

But what that symbol means does not appear to ever be explained. Does anybody know what it's trying to convey? Thanks.

Comment: It's to symbolise that it's output from the command being run

Comment: But it does not appear on all output, just some. And even if a return value of a function is being displayed, the symbol only appears on occasion.

Comment: It looks like it only is used when the return value is "undefined".

Comment: For example, enter any expression, and no symbol appears. Even entering: (function(){})() to evaluate a function with an undefined return, shows "undefined" without the symbol.

Comment: lools like it kinda of highlighting of the end point of returned value if there is more than one value passed to console. consider examples `(function(){return true;})();`, `(function(){console.log('what'); return true;})();` and `(function(){console.log('what'); console.log('abracadabra'); return true;})();`, why it is like this... yeah, really have ho idea, probably enhanced UI?

Comment: @MartyKiker - Does it only appear when calling methods like `Profile` or does it occur for normal JS calls?

Comment: @MartinSmith, normal calls too you could easy check it out in console

Comment: @dmi3y - Not from an IPad I couldn't (or maybe I could but I've never installed it on it)

Comment: Does it ever appear when not using a console method?

Comment: @MartinSmith, sorry :) yep it is occur with normal calls too, if there is multiply lines and when let's say  you have `(function(){})();` returned underfined but without this sign

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever a set of function runs on the command line, the last line of console output is always the returned value of the last operation in the input. The symbol calls out the return value of a function when there has been console output since the start of the command execution. This is to avoid confusion in a case like this:

```
function logVar(someVar) {
    console.log(someVar);
}
```

When you run `logVar` on the console, it outputs the value of `someVar`. However, the return value of `logVar` is also logged (here, `undefined`). It's helpful to have the return value visually distinguished from the logged variable, so you don't look at the last line of the output and wonder, "Why is my variable `undefined`?".

Comment: Yes, repeated testing seems to bear this out. Thanks!

Comment: @apsillers, how than explain this :P `(function(){return 'bebe';})();`

Comment: @dmi3y This doesn't match the case I described: "`The symbol calls out the return value of a function when there has been console output since the start of the command execution.`" Your function terminates without logging anything, so only the return value shows up on the console. Thus, there's no need to specially mark the return value with the symbol. (Or, were you making a joke I didn't get? Your emoticon is sticking out its tongue at me, so I can't be sure!)

Comment: @apsillers, yeh sorry misslooked that, I need take a bit rest