# Chrome DevTools: what's this arrow(<-) meaning?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, google-chrome-devtools

I am confuse about this symbol (<-) in Chrome DevTools

[image: javascript while loop in DevTools Console]

It's return value or console value?

When I run this while loop

```
var i = 0;
while (i < 5) {
    console.log(i);
    i++;
}
```

the console log spits out 4 twice, the last 4 have a (<-) in a front, what's meaning?

Comment: The arrow denotes the value the previous expression evaluates to, though I've no idea why a `while` loop is evaluating to a value. It's not syntactically valid to use `x = while(i < 5) { i++ }` to capture this value, but you *can* capture it by using `x = eval('while (i < 5) { i++ }')`, which assigns `4` to `x`. Pretty interesting.

Comment: Weirder still, it evaluates to the last expression inside the loop body, even if the loop body doesn't return it: `x = true; while (x) { x = false; "a" } // => "a"`

Comment: Also answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713320/whats-the-less-than-dot-symbol-mean-in-chrome-console-output

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has to do with the nature of the `eval` function. Note that:

```
var i = 0, j = while(i < 5) { i++; };
```

Produces a compile error. However,

```
var i = 0, j = eval('while(i < 5) { i++; }');
```

Assigns the value `4` to `j`. Why is this? Quoting from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):

> `eval()` returns the value of the last expression evaluated.

So in short, it evaluates all the calls to `console.log` in your expression, then also logs the return value from the `eval`-ed expression itself, which just happens to be the result of the last `i++`.

Comment: Ah, of course. I find it interesting that the console really is just `eval`ing your input; I thought Chrome itself would have a more "direct" means of evaluating your input.

Comment: @meagar I would say that chrome *is* "directly" evaluating the code, and `eval` is just a wrapper around that. :)