# Browser console output has a mysterious number in for loop with settimeout?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout

Running this on console displays some details right after, followed by the actual console logs. What does those details mean in different browser?

## ```js
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(i);
        }, 0);
    }
```

## [image]

## [image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about, maybe you could attach a screenshot?

Comment: What does stuff like `< 290 = $1 ` mean???

Comment: so function scoped variables, by the time your function in your setTimeout is evaluated, i is already at 10 (since javascript is singleThreaded, your callback function will only happen after the browser has the time to execute your callback). You should either bind i to your function, or create a new function that explicitely sets the timeout for a single value of i

Comment: Also I wouldn't call `10` "weird".  It's a fairly normal number.

Comment: Isn't the question about what `< 290 = $1, < 564 = $2, etc` means?

Comment: @AnotherDev that's certainly *my* question, but nothing in the code posted would print that out.

Comment: @AnotherDev - I have added snapshots now

Comment: @pointy - The question is not about the code. It is about the browser console log.

Comment: @PrabhakarKasi the way you had originally stated the question was confusing and made it seem like it was about the code. Why else would three separate people provide the same answer? Check my answer though - I have updated it to answer what you have asked in the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're scheduling 10 `console.log` statements at the end of the call stack (when the function returns after the for loop has completed). Since `i` is `10` at this point, it prints `10` as many times as you've called `setTimeout` with that handler.

**EDIT**

Upon clarification of the question, what you are seeing is the [value of the last expression evaluated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820746/chrome-devtools-whats-this-arrow-meaning). In this case it is the value of the last timeout you had set. `window.setTimeout` returns an ID that is cancellable and unique for the tab session. In this case, it seems like the browsers are incrementing a count they already had stored, so you're getting increments of 10 because you're calling `setTimeout` 10 times in the loop.

Comment: Yep I came to that conclusion. But I quit the browser and ran the code. Chrome started at 14 and incremented to 24,34,44. FF started at 27 and incremented 37,47. After 2 mins break, FF showed 296 and incremented to 306. In safari started with 74 and increment to 84,94,104...?

Answer (score 0):

Your `setTimeout()` calls create functions that all reference the exact same variable, that `i` defined in the `for` loop. When the loop is finished, the value of `i` will be `10`, so that's what's logged when the timer handlers fire.

Comment: Yep I came to that conclusion. But I quit the browser and ran the code. Chrome started at 14 and incremented to 24,34,44. FF started at 27 and incremented 37,47. After 2 mins break, FF showed 296 and incremented to 306. In safari started with 74 and increment to 84,94,104...?