# How is this setTimeout working? what is 49221 and how is console.log.bind working?

Tags: javascript, console, bind, settimeout, console.log

How is this setTimeout working? what is 49221 and how is console.log.bind working?

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(console.log.bind(console, i), 0);
}
```

OUTPUT

49221

0

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

Comment: [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: this code does not print 49221

Comment: @madox2: If you literally copy and paste it into the web console of your favorite browser, it does print a seemingly-random number before the 0.

Comment: The `49221` is the ID of the timeout, the return value of `setTimeout`. It's the "return value" of the `for` loop. You would only see that if you run the code in the console. See also [Browser console output has a mysterious number in for loop with settimeout?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33003229/218196)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thats right, I did not expect it had been pasted to console..

Comment: @madox2: Understandably! :-)

Answer (score 2):

The fact you're seeing a number before `0` tells me you're pasting this into your browser console. You're seeing that number because it's the handle of the last timer created in the loop. The `for` loop will (this may surprise many reading this, it certainly did me when I first learned of it) result in the return value of the last statement executed in the last execution of its body block. In this case, that's the return value of `setTimeout`, which is a number: The handle you'd use if you wanted to cancel the timer. (The spec's a bit hard to follow, but it's in [§13.7.4.7](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-for-statement-runtime-semantics-labelledevaluation).)

The reason it then goes on to show 0 through 9 is that it schedules 10 timed callbacks to `console.log`, by creating *bound functions* via `Function#bind`. Each of those functions, when called, will turn around and call `console.log` with `this` referring to `console` and passing along the argument given to it (`i`).

Hence: If you paste that into your console, you'll see the last timer handle followed by 0 through 9.

---

About that "`for` has a result" thing, try this in your browser console:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < 5; ++i) {
    i;
}
```

You'll see `4` in the console. :-)

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/33003229/218196 . Although I like your answer better.

Comment: @FelixKling: Yup, I think so. Nice find.